# Angular Protractor: No specs found error when there is some specific name used

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor

I checked answer to this problem posted earlier but facing very weird problem.

The Proctractor script that I am running works perfectly fine when the name of the script if anything other then "TS001_SR001".  As soon as it is changed to some other name it starts working.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Snippet of the scrtipt below. Name highlighted in bold below which requires change to make it work.

Bery very strange Issue ??? :-(

```
'use strict';
var Application = require('../../Utility/savingsFunctions.js');
describe('**TS001_SR001**', function() {
    var application = new Application('TS001_SR001');

    it('TS001_SR001#should Launch URL',function() {
        application.launchURL();
    });

    it('TS001_SR001#Login to the Fidea', function() {
        application.loginApplication();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Click on Savings Lob', function(){
        application.navLandingPage_Tarrif();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Fill Basic Info', function(){
        application.fillBasicInfo();

    });

    it ('TS001_SR001_Test#Open Policy Insured', function(){
        application.tarrifOpenPolicyHolder();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001_Test#Open Policy Insured min details', function(){
        application.policyHolderInfoMin();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001_Test#Click on Ok button insured page', function(){
        application.tarrifPolicyHolderOKbutton();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Insured same as owner', function(){
        application.insuredSameAsOwner();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001# Target Premiums', function(){
        application.targetPremiums();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001# Regular Payments', function(){
        application.regularPayments();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Initial Payment', function(){
        application.initialPayment();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Next Button: Quote -> Coverage', function(){
        application.nextButtonQuote();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Synthesis Selection', function(){
        application.synthesisSelection();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Savings Selection', function(){
        application.SavingsSelection();
    });

    // it ('TS001_SR001#Death Benefits Selection', function(){
    //            element.all(by.name('membership:smoker')).get(1).click();
    // });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Add death Benefits', function(){
        application.Simulation_Death_Benefits();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Next Button: Coverage -> Contract Info', function(){
        application.nextButtonCoverage();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Add Representative Button', function(){
        application.addRepresentativeButton();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Representative Info Fill', function(){
        application.otherPartyInfoMax('Representative');
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Representative OK Button', function(){
        application.okButtonOtherParties();

    }); 

    it ('TS001_SR001#Payment Mode', function(){
        application.addBillingDetails();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Edit AML Questions', function(){
        application.editAMLQuestion();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Fill AML Questions', function(){
        application.fillAMLQuestions();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Click ok AML Questions', function(){
        application.okButtonAMLQuestion();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Send to Fidea', function(){
        application.sendToFideaButton();
    });

    it ('TS001_SR001#Logout', function(){
        application.logout();
    });

});
```

Config.js

```
'use strict';
var jasminePtorFailfast = require('./Utility/jasminePtorFailfast');
var htmlReporter = require('./Utility/htmlReporter');
var fs = require('fs');
exports.config = {
     /*seleniumAddress: 'http://20.198.238.109:4444/wd/hub',
     seleniumPort: 4444,*/
  suites:
  { 
    //RegressionTest: ['Scripts/NewBusiness/*.js'],
    CustomTest :[
    'Scripts/NewBusiness/TS001_SR001.js'
    ]   
  },
    capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    //<--Starts here --use for multiple instances-->
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 5

   },
   jasmineNodeOpts: {defaultTimeoutInterval: 3000000},
   allScriptsTimeout: 400000,
   getPageTimeout: 50000,
   onComplete: function(){
       //console.log('oncomplete');
   },
   onCleanUp: function() {
       //console.log('onCleanUp');
   },
   beforeLaunch: function() {
       console.log('beforeLaunch');
       // check if folders exists or not, if not create them
       var functionalReportsFolder = 'functionalReports';
       var reportsFolder = 'functionalReports/Reports';
       var reportsScreenshotsFolder = 'functionalReports/reports_screenshots';
       var InvestmentPerf = 'tests/functional/Perf/Investment';
       var SavingsPerf = 'tests/functional/Perf/Savings';
       var perfFile = 'tests/functional/Perf';

       if(!fs.existsSync(perfFile)){
            fs.mkdirSync(perfFile);
            console.log('perfFile created');
       };

       if(!fs.existsSync(functionalReportsFolder)){
            fs.mkdirSync(functionalReportsFolder);
            console.log('functionalReportsFolder created');
       };
       if(!fs.existsSync(reportsFolder)){
            fs.mkdirSync(reportsFolder);
            console.log('reportsFolder created');
       };
       if(!fs.existsSync(reportsScreenshotsFolder)){
            fs.mkdirSync(reportsScreenshotsFolder);
            console.log('reportsScreenshotsFolder created');
       };
       if(!fs.existsSync(InvestmentPerf)){
            fs.mkdirSync(InvestmentPerf);
            console.log('InvestmentPerf created');
       };
       if(!fs.existsSync(SavingsPerf)){
            fs.mkdirSync(SavingsPerf);
            console.log('SavingsPerf created');
       };

   },
   afterLaunch: function() {
        console.log('afterLaunch');
        var htmlreporter = new htmlReporter();
        htmlreporter.readDatafromFile();
        console.log('onto htmlreporter.createHTML(function()');
        htmlreporter.createHTML();
        console.log('onto htmlreporter.writeFile();');
        htmlreporter.writeFile();   
        console.log('completed htmlreporter.writeFile();');
        htmlreporter.deleteFiles();
   },
   onPrepare: function() {
    browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(50000);
    browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25000);
    browser.getCapabilities().then(function (cap) {
      browser.browserName = cap.browserName;
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasminePtorFailfast().launch());
    var disableNgAnimate = function() {
        angular.module('disableNgAnimate', []).run(function($animate) {
            $animate.enabled(false);
        });
    };
    var disableCssAnimate = function() {
        angular.module('disableCssAnimate', []).run(function() {
            var style = document.createElement('style');
            style.type = 'text/css';
            style.innerHTML = '* {' +
                '-webkit-transition: none !important;' +
                '-moz-transition: none !important' +
                '-o-transition: none !important' +
                '-ms-transition: none !important' +
                'transition: none !important' +
                '}';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
        });
    };
    browser.addMockModule('disableCssAnimate', disableCssAnimate);
    browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);
  },
  params:
    {
        wait : 50000,
        waitTime : 3000,
        env:'UAT',
        Url:'http://localhost:8080/#/fidea/'
    }

};
```

Comment: Please post your `config.js` file

Comment: How do you execute your tests?

Comment: Running through protractor conf.js or through our Grunt aommnad